# Union set theory question.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it true that
$$
A \subseteq B, C \subseteq D \implies A\cup C \subseteq B \cup D.
$$
If not would it change anything if $A \cap C, B\cap D = \emptyset$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, here's a proof that uses the rule $\varphi \to \psi \iff \lnot\psi \to \lnot\varphi$, called contraposition. $\lnot\psi \to \lnot\varphi$ is called the contrapositive.

Suppose by way of contrapositive $A \cup C \not\subset B \cup D$.

That means

$$ \exists x \in A \cup C \mathop. x \not\in B \land x \not\in D $$

And therefore

$$ \exists x \in A \mathop. x \not\in B \land x \not\in D \;\;\text{or}\;\; \exists x \in C \mathop. x \not\in B \land x \not\in D $$

And therefore

$$ A \not\subset B \;\;\text{or}\;\; C \not\subset D $$

Applying the contrapositive, we get the following as desired.

$$ \text{If $A \subset B$ and $C \subset D$, then $A \cup C \subset B \cup D$} $$

Comment: Thank you was having trouble writing the statements out.

Comment: I encourage you to think carefully about each of the steps, understand the proof, and then write a separate one yourself from scratch if this is for a problem set itself instead of a non-problem-set exercise. There are other approaches you can take, such as not using the contrapositve. Apologies if I misinterpreted your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is true. To see why note that $A \subseteq A\cup X$ for any set. So $A\subseteq A\cup D\subseteq B\cup D$ and $C\subseteq C\cup D\subseteq B\cup D$. Morevoer, $A\subseteq X$ and $B\subseteq X$ implies that $A\cup B\subseteq X$. Taking all together we arrive at your statement (there is no need for the sets to be disjoint)

Comment: Thanks for this different approach.